What am I missing editing Policy
I'm simply trying to take the default deny template and add a few more tags that I want to get added to the resources. I get an error that says "tagName1" is not allowed. What am I missing?
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
    },
    {
      "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'),('tagName1') ']')]",
      "exists": "false"
    }
  ]
},
"then": {
  "effect": "deny"
}
},
"parameters": {
"tagName": {
  "type": "String",
  "metadata": {
    "displayName": "Tag Name",
    "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
  },
  "tagName1": {
  "type": "String",
  "metadata": {
    "displayName": "Project",
    "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
  }
},


Concatenate the tag names using commas within the concat function.
"field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ',', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",

The problem is with your if block. Since you require the deployment user to specify tagName AND tagName1, you can make use of nested conditions. Your policy definition should look like:
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags['tagName']",
              "exists": "false"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags['tagName1']",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}

You will not need your parameters block.

Using what you put I still get invalid JSON. "Expecting coma or closing brace"

@user770022 Do you want to add the tags with a static value if they're not present? Or do you want to block creation? I'll update my answer if you can tell me.

I dont want to have static tags but I'm not seeing how I can just require the tags without having a value.

@user770022 I've revised the answer. Please accept it if it has resolved your issue.

In your policy, Tag names such as tagName and tagName1, must be separately defined within the parameters object. The concatenated tag names should be used in the field condition of the policy rule to check for their existence.
Here is the updated policy.
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ',', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Tag Name",
            "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'pailot'"
          }
        },
        "tagName1": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Project",
            "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
          }
        }
      }
    }

Output:
The policy is denying the resource group with different tag names.

